# Machine learning kerrnels (how to check if the data is linearly separable in high dimensional space using a given kernel)

Tags: machine-learning

How can I test/check whether a given kernel (example: RBF/ polynomial) does really separate my data?

I would like to know if there is a method (not plotting the data of course) which can allow me to check if a given data set (labeled with two classes) can be separated in high dimensional space?

Comment: @lejlot, oh, removed my comment. Seems like I misunderstood the question. I assumed that `linearly separable` in this case meant `the model can actually separate` real data.

Comment: @cel, OP clearly stats "a given data set", which is just a finite sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no, there is no general way. However, for some kernels you can easily say that... everything is separable. This property, proved in many forms (among other by Schoenberg) says for example that if your kernel is of form K(x,y) = f(||x-y||^2) and f is:

- ifinitely differentible
- **completely monotonic** (which more or less means that if you take derivatives, then the first one is negative, next positive, next negative, ... )
- positive

then it will **always be able to separate every binary labeled, consistent dataset** (there are no two points of the exact same label). Actually it says even more - that you can exactly interpolate, meaning, that even if it is a regression problem - you will get zero error. So in particular multi-class, multi-label problems also will be linearly solvable (there exists linear/multi-linear model which gives you a correct interpolation).

However, if the above properties do not hold, it does not mean that your data cannot be perfectly separated. This is only "one way" proof.

In particular, this class of kernels include RBF kernel, thus it will **always** be able to separate **any training set** (this is why it overfits so easily!)

So what about in the other way? Here you have to first fix hyperparameters of the kernel and then you can also answer it through optimization - solve hard-margin SVM problem (C=inf) and it will find a solution iff data is separable.

Comment: Hmm, good to know, can you give links to related articles/papers/info? I want to know more about this.

Comment: these are actually basics of interpolation. For example "approximation theory and methods" by Powell. In general - these are very old results, simply under different names. Here, it boils down to answering the question "Is kernel matrix invertible", if it is - even linear regression will solve it. Remember that this is **not** what machine learning is about. You should think about **generalization**, while this simply means **you can overfit to the maximum**, nothing more.